# Understanding the following piece of code in smalltalk

Tags: smalltalk

I am trying to understand the following piece of code in smalltalk

```
Character extend [
   isGraph [
      ^ (Character space < self) & (self <= $~)
   ]
   visible [
      self isGraph ifTrue: [^ '$', self asString]
                   ifFalse: [^ self asInteger printStringRadix: 16]
   ]
]
```

So basically what that code is doing is to extend the functionality of character by adding two new functions to it. IsGraph returns a boolean value, but I don't understand its purpose. How do you interpret (Character space < self) & (self <= $~)?. Somehow the message space is sent to character and that returns something which is compared to self and then self is compared to $~. Can also someone explain the meaning of the symbol ',' in the iftrue block?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

welcome to StackOverflow.

First of all the code is adding two new methods and not functions as this is object-oriented programming.

When you send the `space` message to the `Character` class it will return you an instance if that class which represents the space character. `isGraph` probably means "is graphical" because the characters that precede space in the ASCII table do not have a graphical representation (they are NULL, CR, ESC, etc.) as well as the DEL character that follows `~`. Thus with `isGraph`, you check whether a character is between space and `~` on ASCII table.

`visible` returns a visible representation of a character and relies on `isGraph` to decide whether to return the actual character or its integer ASCII representation. The actual character is returned in the Smalltalk's character literal format e.g. `$a` is used for character `a`, `$3` is used for character `3`. Strings are concatenated with the `,` message.

Actually, one of the main points of Smalltalk is understandability. Thus you should be always able to debug a small piece of code or look at the implementations of a message (like `,` in your case). But I suspect that you use something like GNU Smalltalk that lacks many of these features.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Uko. I have two more questions regarding the following line of code:^ self asInteger printStringRadix: 16 ... I understand that you send messages to objects in smalltalk , but I don't understand here what is going on. How many messages are being sent, two or one?. Is it saying return self as an integer and print it?

Comment: @Dan return is not a message, it just specifies the type of a statement. There can be two types: (normal) expression statements and return statements. Then the content of the statement is `self asInteger printStringRadix: 16`. You send `asInteger` to `self` (a character) and get back the integer representation (ASCII code) of that character. Then you send `printStringRadix:` to the received integer with the parameter `16` and get back the string representation of the integer in the base of 16.